# Integrate Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, visual-studio-2013

Need to integrate this PowerShell script into my C# Assembly code. No idea how to do this. If any other information is needed please do not hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance.

PowerShell Script:

```
#Script that does the linking and renaming:

# Creates a variable called IncidentID and points Incident # to it for use within the script
Param(
[string]$IncidentID
)

# Load the SMlets module
Import-Module SMlets 

# Get the Incident Class
$IncClass = Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.Incident$

# Get the RMA Class
$RMAClass = Get-SCSMClass -Name COMPANY.RMA.Class

# Build the Filter String
$FilterStr = "ID -eq " + $IncidentID

# Find the Incident we need to link to an RMA
$Inc = Get-SCSMObject -Class $IncClass -Filter $FilterStr
$RMAIncText = "[Linked to Incident " + $Inc.ID + "]"
$RMADescription = $RMAIncText 
New-SCSMObject -Class $RMAClass -PropertyHashtable (@{Title = $Inc.Title; Description = $RMADescription})

# Find the new RMA to be linked
$FilterStr = "Description -eq '$RMADescription'"
$RMA = Get-SCSMObject -Class $RMAClass -Filter $FilterStr

#Set RMA Number Variable
$RMANumber = $RMA.RMA_ID; 

#Clean up DisplayName, Title and Description  
$RMA | Set-SCSMObject -PropertyHashtable @{"DisplayName"  =  $RMANumber; "Title" =  $RMANumber; "Description" =  $RMANumber;}

## Create an Incident Related Items instance referencing the new RMA
$RWIClass = Get-SCSMRelationshipClass -Name System.WorkItemRelatesToWorkItem$
New-SCSMRelationshipObject -Relationship $RWIClass -Source $Inc -Target $RMA -Bulk

# Unload the SMlets module
Remove-Module SMlets
```

Assembly Code:

```
public class RMATask : ConsoleCommand
    {
        public RMATask()
        {
        }
        public override void ExecuteCommand(IList<NavigationModelNodeBase> nodes, NavigationModelNodeTask task, ICollection<string> parameters)
        {
            IManagementGroupSession session = (IManagementGroupSession)FrameworkServices.GetService<IManagementGroupSession>();
            EnterpriseManagementGroup emg = session.ManagementGroup;

            ManagementPack mp = emg.ManagementPacks.GetManagementPack(new Guid("a82d62c5-ece0-35fd-a266-9afa246dea78"));
            ManagementPackClass mpc = emg.EntityTypes.GetClass(new Guid("4b081ab1-f48e-9c62-77bc-76bc31349030"));
            ManagementPackObjectTemplate mpt = emg.Templates.GetObjectTemplate(new Guid("92ed7c4d-aff5-819e-90f8-c92064c50cd6"));

            NavigationModelNodeBase nodeIn = nodes[0];

            NavigationModelNodeBase nmnbNew;
            NavigationModelNodeTask nmntNew = NavigationTasksHelper.CreateNewInstanceLink(mpc, mpt);
            Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.GenericForm.GenericCommon.MonitorCreatedForm(nodeIn, nmntNew, out nmnbNew);
        }
    }
```

For those interested in the details here they are:
Problem
Basically, we have help desk analysts who generate the incidents. SOMETIMES, they may have a need to generate an RMA (Return Merchandise Authorization, if you don't know what that means, just know that it is another form they need to fill out), and that RMA needs to be associated with an incident. An incident does not REQUIRE to have an RMA, but every RMA needs to be attached to its appropriate parent incident.

To do this I created a new class called COMPANY.RMA.Class, created a new form from scratch in Visual Studio, and packaged the MP (Management Pack) XML and form assembly (.dll) into an MPB (management pack bundle).
I uploaded this to the console, and created a new console task called "Create RMA" that became visible when selecting the incident module.

This task would launch my PowerShell script, which in turn would take the ID of the incident selected or opened, create an RMA object, and associate the RMA object created with the ID # of the Incident (allowing it to be seen later in the "Related Items" Tab of the incident).
However, I ran into a problem here. I create the linking functionality correctly, but I cannot get the RMA form to automatically open up after it is created. Instead, when the task is run, it creates the object and saves it, but the analyst has to close the incident and reopen it to refresh the new data, navigate to the "Related Items" tab, and select the newly created RMA to open it up and fill out the form. This is alot of extra work and should be eliminated.
The correct functionality should be to create the RMA form, associate it with the open/selected incident, and launch the RMA form it just created to allow the analyst to fill in its details.

Apparently there is no function to call/launch the form directly from the console task. It seems I must modify the assembly code directly to be able to access the SCSM SDK (the layer I need to be working in). This is where I am lost - I have no idea how to convert my PowerShell script to C# Assembly code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you powershell script and c# code do? What do you mean by *integrating* them? Do you think to try to format your question?

Comment: If you are looking to [run powershell from inside your c# app](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=run%20powershell%20inside%20c%23) there are a [few](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx) [sites](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/bruceky/How-to-Embedding-PowerShell-Within-a-C-Application) that can help you.

Comment: @admdrew I have asked a different question before on this forum, and was scolded for being too specific and having too much text in my question. I attempted to shorten it and now I have the same reaction -_-

Comment: @SirLearnAlot, it is definitely a balance.  The skill is to be able to give enough information that directs us to the problem without pasting a wall of code.  Keep posting questions and honing that skill.  You'll get there. :)

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [PowerShell class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) to host PowerShell in your app.

The host application can define the runspace where commands are run, open sessions on a local or remote computer, and invoke the commands either synchronously or asynchronously based on the needs of the application.
There's guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I can add this to my .dll assembly code? So I add the Powershell assembly reference, and create a powershell namespace or something?

Comment: @SirLearnAlot Yes. I'd suggest playing with one of the [code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706597(v=vs.85).aspx) in a simple standalone app first.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this alternatively.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
/// using System.Threading.Tasks; <- .NET 4.5 only
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ConnectorFramework;
// using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Core;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Extensions.Shared;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.FormsInfra;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Core.Connection;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.DataModel;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess.DataAdapters;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.WpfWizardFramework;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ServiceManager.Application.Common;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ConsoleFramework;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.GenericForm;
// using System.Management.Automation;
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

namespace COMPANY.RMA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>

    class RMATask : CreateWithLinkHandler
    {
        public RMATask()
        {


            try
            {
                // Sealed Class GUID
                this.createClassGuid = new Guid("9ebd95da-1b16-b9ea-274d-6b0c16ce1bf3");
                this.classToDelegate = new Dictionary<Guid, CreateLinkHelperCallback>()
                {
                    { ApplicationConstants.WorkItemTypeId, new CreateLinkHelperCallback (this.WorkItemCallback) }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception exc1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc1.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        public void WorkItemCallback(IDataItem RMAForm, IDataItem IncidentForm)
        {
            try
            {
                // Note to self: RelatedWorkItems should be in MP XML as alias under TypeProjections
                if (RMAForm != null && RMAForm.HasProperty("RelatedWorkItems"))
                {
                    // Perform Linking
                    RMAForm["RelatedWorkItems"] = IncidentForm;
                    // Copy Incident Title to RMA Title
                    RMAForm["Title"] = IncidentForm["Title"];
                    // Copy Incident Description to RMA Description
                    RMAForm["Description"] = IncidentForm["Description"];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc2.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```